# How to implement datepicker in Livewire?

Tags: laravel, datepicker, tailwind-css, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am learning Livewire and I want to use datepicker in my form. I found one helpful component from [tailwindcomponents.com](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/datepicker-with-tailwindcss-and-alpinejs) but not able to understand how to convert it into a livewire reusable component.

tailwindcomponents: https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/datepicker-with-tailwindcss-and-alpinejs

I have created a blade file in the view directory but not able to understand how HTML and JS code to be added. Also is it possible to access birthday value like **wire:model="birthday"**

> <x-input.datepicker wire:model="birthday" id="datepicker"/>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [**Pikaday**](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday) for this task:

```
npm i pikaday
```

In app.js:

```
window.Pikaday = require('pikaday');
```

Create new blade component

```
views/components/input/date.blade.php
```

with

```
@props([
    'error' => null
])

<div
    x-data="{ value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')) }"
    x-on:change="value = $event.target.value"
    x-init="
        new Pikaday({ field: $refs.input, 'format': 'DD.MM.YYYY', firstDay: 1 });"
>
    <input 
        {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }} 
        x-ref="input"
        x-bind:value="value" 
        type="text" 
        class="pl-10 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-lg bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 @if($error) focus:ring-danger-500 focus:border-danger-500 border-danger-500 text-danger-500 pr-10 @else focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 @endif rounded-md" 
    />
</div>
```

Use it like this:

```
<x-input.date wire:model="birthday" :error="$errors->first('birthday')"/>
```

Comment: Worked great, nice & neat answer. Just needed the CSS to complete the picture. Also for others, you may need to `npm i moment` if it doesn't exist in your project.

Comment: I needed to update app.js part in order to get it work to this:
`import pikaday from 'pikaday';
window.Pikaday = pikaday;`

Comment: Also to app.css:
`@import 'pikaday/css/pikaday.css';`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, but also needed a **time picker**. Based on the answer by Upvote, I built a solution using [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/).

Instead of installing Pikaday, install Flatpickr using the [install guide](https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/).

Create a new component called `views/components/input/date.blade.php` and use something like this:

```
@props([
    'error' => null
])

<div
    x-data="{ value: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')) }"
    x-on:change="value = $event.target.value"
    x-init="flatpickr($refs.input, {enableTime: true, dateFormat: 'Z', defaultHour: 18, time_24hr: true })"
>
    <input 
        {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }} 
        x-ref="input"
        x-bind:value="value" 
        type="text" 
        class="pl-10 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-lg bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 @if($error) focus:ring-danger-500 focus:border-danger-500 border-danger-500 text-danger-500 pr-10 @else focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 @endif rounded-md" 
    />
</div>
```

If you do not want to use 24 hour time format, remove the `time_24hr: true` option.
You can then use the component in the same way Upvote described.